Let $x,y,z$ are selected from set of natural numbers. Find the probability that $x^2+y^2+z^2$ is divisible by $5$

Let $x,y,z$ are selected from set of natural numbers. Find the probability that $x^2+y^2+z^2$ is divisible by $5$

My Method: I took set of first $10$ natural numbers. Let say set is $S=\{1,2,3,...,10\}$
In this set there are $5$ types of numbers that is $5k, 5k+1, 5k+2, 5k+3, 5k+4$
We want three numbers such that sum of squares of these numbers is divisible by $5$
Case $1$: all numbers are of $5k$ types so in this case there are $8$ possible numbers.
I am listing them here $(5,5,5), (10,10,10), (5,5,10),(5,10,5), (10,5,5), (10,10,5), (10,5,10), (5,10,10)$
Case $2$ Numbers are of type $(5k, 5k+1, 5k+2)$ types. In this case there are $2\cdot 2\cdot2$ ways to select numbers for example $(5, 6, 7), (5,6,2), (10, 6, 7), (10, 6, 2), (5, 1, 7), (5, 1, 2), (10, 1,7), (10, 1, 2)$
Also each of them can be permutate between $x,y,z$ in $3!$ ways
so total answer of case $2$ is $8\cdot 6=48$
Similarly for numbers of type $(5k,5k+1, 5k+3), (5k,5k+2,5k+4), (5k, 5k+3, 5k+4)$
So in total there are $8+ (48\cdot 4)= 200$ possibility for numbers divisible by $5$.
And total numbers are $10\cdot 10 \cdot 10=1000$
Hence the probability is $\dfrac{200}{1000}$ but given answer is $\dfrac{176}{1000}$
Can you help me find error in my Approach?
And my second question is what if in question insted of natural numbers we consider all integers.
New Update: Here I am attaching Image of actual question (question number 54 )and one more question (question number 8) I asked in comment section with solution provided





First of all, there is no such thing as a random selection from the set of natural numbers, or from the integers, for that matter.  That is, there is no uniform probability measure on an infinite discrete set.  What is presumably meant is the limit as $N \to \infty$ when $x,y,z$ are selected (independently) from the natural numbers $< N$, or in the case of the integers, from the natural numbers in $(-N, N)$.    For this, your answer of $200/1000$ or $1/5$ is correct.  I have no idea how "they" got $176/1000$.

To improve this question, you could say that $x,y,z$ are chosen in such a way that the probability of $x$ being a multiple of 5 is $\frac{1}{5}$ and similarly for $y,z$ (independently). Even then I'm not sure it works for the reason @RobertIsrael mentions above.

@RobertIsrael Also in one more question  it reads as Two non-negative integers are chosen at random. The probability that the sum of their
squares is divisible by 5 is and given answer is $\dfrac{9}{25}$ so is this question wrong too?

If we restrict $x^2 + y^2+ z^2 \leq 100$, we get the probability $\frac{3}{17} = 0.176471$ but that seems kind of haphazard :D. Or, for $\leq 507$ we get even closer: $60/341 = 0.175953$.

As the size of the subset of integers gets larger, I get $\frac15$ as well. Does the book give any explanation of their answer?

To write the discrete probability there needs to be some bound on $x$, $y$, and $z$.  Or it could be a limit sort of problem.  But really this needs to be clarified in the question to make much sense of it to answer.

Since the residues of $x,y,z$ mod $5$ determine $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 \mod 5$, you may consider $x$, $y$, $z$ are chosen independently and uniformly from ${0,1,2,3,4}$.  There are $25$ cases that produce success: $(0,0,0), (0,1,2), (0,1,3), (0,2,4), (0,3,4)$ and their permutations.  So the correct answer is $25/5^3 = 1/5$.

In the case of two integers, the possibilities are $(0,0), (1,2), (1,3), (2,4), (3,4)$ and their permutations, so the answer should indeed be $9/25$.

@user But for $x + y + z$ the correct answer is also $1/5$.

@mathophile aits question? seems like you are preparing for jee advanced....

Taking larger consecutive subsets of $\mathbb{Z}$, I get the same answer. Here is my approach

There are $3$ quadratic residues mod $5$: $0$, $1$, $-1$. To make a sum of $0$, we have
$$
0+0+0\quad\text{with probability }\frac15\cdot\frac15\cdot\frac15=\frac1{125}
$$
and the $6$ permutations of
$$
\overset{\underbrace{2,3}}{-1}+\overset{\underbrace{1,4}}{1}+\overset{\underbrace{0}}{0}\quad\text{with probability }\frac25\cdot\frac25\cdot\frac15=\frac4{125}
$$
Thus, the probability of getting a sum of $0$ is
$$
\frac1{125}+6\cdot\frac4{125}=\frac15
$$
